# Xarray find lat/lon coordinates for maximum/minimum values for each timestep

Tags: python, python-xarray

As the title says, supposing I have a `ds` with coords: `[time lat lon]`, how can I obtain for each timestep in `time` the pair of `['lat','lon']` in which the maximum(or minimum) value for a given variable is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`xr.Dataset.idxmax`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.idxmax.html) to find the index label of the maximum along a dimension (one at a time). Same for [`xr.Dataset.idxmin`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.idxmin.html).

```py
max_lons = ds.max(dim="lat").idxmax(dim="lon")
max_lats = ds.max(dim="lon").idxmax(dim="lat")
```

The results will be datasets, with each variable giving the lon or lat coresponding to the maximum in each time step for that variable.